# How to put Bibliography at the end of each section in my thesis?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, bibunits

I use following to have reference at the end of each section. After compiling my latex file any thing does not appear. How to solve this problem??

```
\section{Target}
\begin{bibunit}
My Text with a lot of citations, \cite{a}
\cite{b}
\putbib[PhD_thesis] %PhD_thesis.bib is my bib file
\end{bibunit}
```

Comment: Your question will be clearer and attract quicker and better answers if you provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: You mention running LaTeX twice. Did you run BibTeX as well, by running the command `bibtex bu1`? After running this command, remember to run LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: To achieve this is pretty easy with package `biblatex`.

Comment: You need to run `bibtex` for each section of the document - as Mico says, `bibtex bu1` for the first section - `bibtex bu2` for the second etc. `biblatex`/`biber` can handle this automatically, but `bibtex` can't. Generally, if you run `bibtex` in your editor, it will run `bibtex` using for the main document only, which is not going to cut it if you have separate bibs for each section.

Comment: Just as @Mico said e.g. `bibtex bu1` for the first section. Then `bibtex bu2` for the second and so on for each section which has its own bibliography.

Comment: I do not understand, I have all my references in one bib file. Do you mean I separate my bib file in two or more different files?? And then put each of them at each section? like for section 1 \bibliography{PhD_thesis1} and then for section two \bibliography{PhD_thesis2} and so on?

Comment: @user3559542 - You're making this more complicated than it is. First, run LaTeX on your tex file. If the file is called, say, `main.tex`, you need to run `pdflatex main`. Given that the `bibunits` package has been loaded, files called `bu1.aux`, `bu2.aux`, etc will be created by LaTeX -- one file per `bibunit` environment in the tex file. Second, run BibTeX on each of the `bu<x>` files: `bibtex bu1`, `bibtex bu2`, etc. BibTeX will create files called `bu1.bbl`, `bu2.bbl`, etc. Finally, run LaTeX twice more, to incorparate the material in bbl files and will will resolve all `\cite` commands.

Comment: How I run BibTex on each of the bu<x> files??

Comment: Do you know how to open a command window and switch to the directory where the main tex file is located?

Comment: No, I do not know. Know I see in my folder that the bibunits package: bu1.aux, bu2.aux, and bu3.aux has been loaded there. Please help me to know how to deal with it

Comment: You haven't told us which operating system you run, which TeX distribution you use, etc. How are we supposed to give more specific instructions if you don't provide these important pieces of information? I suggest you start by finding out how to go about opening a command window on your system. This will be an important skill to have in any case.

Comment: TeXstudio on windows 7

Comment: So, find out how to open a so-called "Command Prompt" window in Windows. Next, once you've opened such a window, find out how to go to the working directory that contains your tex file. Once you're there, type "bibtex bu1", "bibtex bu2", etc.

Comment: I did it. now I have, how I can put it as a subsection know? in my content it does not show as a subsection? it is shown just as a page? How I can remove it from content?

Comment: @user3559542 - I suggest you write a new query on this new topic. Please make the query informative about your system.

Comment: Dear Mirco: Thank you,  But why my citations are not in order inside text ?? it start inside my text  by cite no.28?how to solve this problem

Comment: now works, but citations are not in order inside text ?? it start inside my text by cite no.28?how to solve this problem

Comment: @Mico Reading just the last omments, you seemed to have helped. Answer? Or mark as duplicate?

Comment: @Johannes_B - Done. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I found a blog which describes a solution based on BIBER.

> https://texblog.org/2012/10/22/multiple-bibliographies-with-biblatex/

Here a copy of the sources:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{knuth1986texbook,
  keywords = {book},
  title={The texbook},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Bibby, D.},
  volume={1993},
  year={1986},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
@article{knuth1977fast,
  keywords = {article},
  title={Fast pattern matching in strings},
  author={Knuth, D.E. and Morris Jr, J.H. and Pratt, V.R.},
  journal={SIAM journal on computing},
  volume={6},
  number={2},
  pages={323--350},
  year={1977},
  publisher={SIAM}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{First}
\begin{refsection}
Citation section \thesection: \cite{knuth1986texbook}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\section{Second}
\begin{refsection}
Citation section \thesection: \cite{knuth1977fast}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recommendation:

- First, run LaTeX on your tex file. If the tex file is called, say, `main.tex`, you need to run

  ```
  pdflatex main
  ```

  (or `xelatex main` or `lualatex main`, as appropriate). You can do this either from a command line or from within your tex-aware editor.

  Given that the `bibunits` package has been loaded, files called `bu1.aux`, `bu2.aux`, etc will be created by LaTeX -- one file per `bibunit` environment in the tex file. Note that this will happen irrespective of whether your bibtex *inputs* are in a single .bib file or are contained in multiple .bib files.
- Second, open a command window and run BibTeX on each of the `bu<x>` files:

  ```
  bibtex bu1
  bibtex bu2
  ```

  etc. Do *not* run BibTeX on the main tex file, i.e., do not run `bibtex main`.

  BibTeX will create files called `bu1.bbl`, `bu2.bbl`, etc. as well as associated log files (with extension `blg`). Pay attention to any error and/or warning messages you may get at the BibTeX stage. They may alert you to syntax errors in the bib entries or the `\cite` commands in `main.tex`. Resolve them and re-run LaTeX and BibTeX as outlined above.
- Finally, run `pdflatex main` twice more to incorporate the material in the bbl files, in the form of (a) formatted (and grouped) references and (b) citation call-outs.